# Можно ли поменять jdk в написанном проекте?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdk11

Есть проект, написанный на jdk 1.8. Я установил новую java 13. Вот пытаюсь поменять jdk в project structure в Intellij Idea и ничего не получается. Требует 1.8.

Comment: Что-то не так делаете. У Java полная обратная совместимость.

Comment: Да, я знаю. Но когда пытаюсь подключить sdk пишет "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK"

Comment: Выбранная вами директория не является корнем JDK.

Comment: Но в переменную окружения ее писал. И простенькие java файлы запускаются из консоли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема исчезла после обновления Intellij Idea.